# get list of values in a select from post html form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, html-post

This is my form:

```
    <form action="script.php" method="post">
    <SELECT id="avail" name="avail[]" size=5>                                       
           <option value="Avocado">Avocado</option>                                     
           <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
           <option value="Black pepper">Black pepper</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

How can I get the values available in the select menu from script.php ???

`$_POST["avail"]` doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['avail'][0]` will contain the select's value the way you have it.  You are using an array by specifying `name='avail[]'` in the select.  You don't need to do this unless you have multiple selects with the same name.

Comment: but I want all the select in the list...not the selected

Comment: $_POST cannot give you the list of the values available.  It only provides the user input / selected values.